# XSLT - analyse following text value

Tags: regex, xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have a XML that text() node is not correctly formatted,

example:

```
<section>
    <p>A number,of words have, been, suggested,as sources for,the term,</p>
</section>
```

Here after some ',' there are no space character and some does. what I need to do is if ',' not followed by a space character add a '*' character after the ',' character.

so, expected result,

```
<section>
    <p>A number,*of words have, been, suggested,*as sources for,*the term*</p>
</section>
```

I think this can be done using regular expression but how can I select , characters that are not followed by space in regular expression in XSLT. also, some , exist just before the closing element (last , in the input) and I need to select those , as well.

```
<xsl:template match="para">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex=",\s*">
                <xsl:matching-substring>
                    <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(1)"/>
                    <xsl:value-of select="'*'"/>
                </xsl:matching-substring>
                <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </xsl:non-matching-substring>
            </xsl:analyze-string>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've replaced the last `,` in your input with `,*` though your statement doesn't say that. I hope the below XSLT helps:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="p/text()">
        <xsl:value-of select="replace(., ',([^\s]|$)',',*$1')"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*, node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<section>
   <p>A number,*of words have, been, suggested,*as sources for,*the term,*</p>
</section>
```

Here, the regex, `,([^\s]|$)` matches the comma and the first character after that if not a space character; `,*$1` replaces the `,` with `,*` and keeps the matched group intact.

Comment: or a bit shorter by using `\S` to match non-whitespace character : `,(\S|$)`